# Particular URL redirect to http if request come from particular host

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, ssl, url-rewriting

Web server is apache, ssl configured, listening on 443,
All http requests will be redirected to https using rewrite rule

Issues is all url's are serving through https, but we want to connect to the web server through http if the request is coming for particular url  from particular host, rest all should be served through ssl

Example:

When we access the url `/test/devices`, normally it will server through ssl like
`https://example.com/test/devices`

But when we access the url `/test/devices` from host 10.1.2.3 the request should server through http protocol instead of https

This should happen only from this host, if any other hosts access this url they should be served through ssl

The current rewrite url we are using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /test/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The first rule will redirect all requests to test folder

The second rule will redirect requests to https

Appreciate your responses!

Comment: Show your current rewrite rules

Comment: Hi added the current rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add another RewriteCond to exclude redirect for this IP:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=10.1.2.3
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: This works if we access web server directly, but if there is a load balancer before web servers can we X-Forwarded-For like below RewriteCond %{X-Forwarded-For} !=10.1.2.3, to identify the original client ip address